# Using ModelBuilder to iterate through fields in shapefile and create raster from each

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, rasterization, iterator

I have the exact same problem as [Iterate Through Fields in Model Builder [sic]](https://community.esri.com/thread/56324) at GeoNet but all the solutions proposed there involved ArcPy and I'm not familiar with that program. I would like to use ModelBuilder to do the exact same thing: iterate through fields in a polygon shapefile and, for each one, create a raster based on the value in the field.

Any suggestions?

I'm using ArcMap and here's what I have so far.

[image]

The error message reads:

> ERROR 000728: Field 1 does not exist within table
>
> Failed to execute (Polygon to Raster).

I am trying to iterate through fields, not values of a single field. The shapefile does have some ID fields that are string format though and which I don't want to convert. However, there are 26 Double fields that I do want to convert.

Comment: What happens when you run that model?

Comment: Please use the edit button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.  Is that the entire message?  What field are you iterating?  What values are in that field?

Comment: Are you trying to iterate through all the fields in your shapefile, or are you trying to iterate through all the values in a single field of your shapefile?

Comment: @PolyGeo Yes, sorry. I added the error message to the original question. I am trying to iterate through fields, not values of a single field. The shapefile does have some ID fields that are string format though and which I don't want to convert. However, there are 26 Double fields that I do want to convert. Should I drop the string fields? What about the OBJECTID field, which can't be deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ArcMap there is no out of the box ModelBuilder tool that iterates over fields, they iterate over rows. As indicated in the comments the way to do this is through some simple Python code which you have dismissed in your question.  This leaves you only one option, replicate the tool and set the field parameter to be each of your fields for each tool as shown below.

You give no indication of how many fields you want to convert by, if a few, then it literally takes seconds to set up the model below. If it is hundreds I would be questioning why you have a dataset structured so.

[image: Suggested model]

Comment: ArcGIS Pro has an Iterate Fields tool.

Comment: @PolyGeo can you please provide a link to this iterator? I can't find it.

Comment: It’s at https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-fields.htm

Comment: @PolyGeo, Interesting if one drills down into the help file (as I did) into the [model builder section](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geoprocessing/modelbuilder/iterators-for-looping.htm) there is no mention of this useful iterator! Have left feedback on the ESRI site.

Comment: OK, good to know. Thanks everyone. I'll give these things a try.